# Problema con una expresión regular buscando múltiples coincidencias

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente texto: ""Un buúho bu bu gorjeó". Estoy intentando crear una expresión regular que encuentre todas las palabras "bu" en la frase anterior(que deberían ser 3) pero no funciona correctamente. Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
 let prueba = "Un buúho bu bu gorjeó";
 let expReg1 = /bu*/g
 console.log(expReg1.exec(prueba));
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por una parte, el método `RegExp.prototype.exec()` ejecuta una búsqueda de acuerdo a la expresión regular que se use. Lo importante, es saber que este método tiene un estado interno cuando se usa la bandera g al final, como la que tu presentas. `/bu*/g`.

Se almacena un valor interno que representa el último índice en el que se encontró un match, para que así llamadas consecuentes a la función retornen el siguiente match.

Por lo que podemos utilizar un ciclo para que busquemos las palabras que coinciden con la expresión regular en todo el string, y no solo el primero.

```js
let prueba = "Un buúho bu bu gorjeó";
let rex = /bu*/g;
let resultado;

while (resultado = rex.exec(prueba)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
    console.log("el match es " + resultado[0]);
    console.log("el match empieza en la posición " + resultado.index);
    console.log("el match termina en la posición " + rex.lastIndex)
}
```

Por cierto, tu expresión regular no es correcta en la medida que también va a coincidir con palabras de la forma `buuu`, es decir, con cualquier cantidad de u's y según veo no es lo que deseas. Esto sucede porque el carácter `*` hace match con cero o más instancias del token inmediatamente anterior, en tu caso el carácter u. Por lo que incluso `b` sería un match.

Por lo que sencillamente podrías usar la expresión `/bu/g`.

Comment: Gracias! pero quedo con una duda. No se supone que la bandera g buscaría en todo el string?

Comment: Si, de hecho, si no la usas en este ejemplo, se genera un ciclo infinito, porque siempre hará match con la primera instancia.

Comment: muchas gracias!